# FontAwesome icons are larger since upgrading to version 5 pro

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

i have recently upgraded all of my projects to font-awesome 5 pro. Since the update the icons appear larger than they were before even though i am using the same font size with them.
Does anyone have an idea on how i can change that? I mean how i can change the general size of all the icons without editing all the css classes across the projects.

EXAMPLE:

[image]

Comment: adjust the font-size

Comment: The problem is that there are many different font sizes used across all the projects. It would be a lot of work changing all the sizes. I am wondering if there would be a way to alter the default size in general.

Comment: share your code then and show us how they are different so we can help

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the difference. The code is the regular code from the font awesome website.

Comment: this is have nothing to do with font-size I guess ... they are simply different, which is logical from version to version. so you need to adapt your code